# Python: Wrong directory

Tags: python

I have written code on python for sentiment analysis of movie reviews

```
import re
import nltk
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from  sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def lemmatize(l):
   # proc = CoreNLP("pos", corenlp_jars=["stanford-corenlp-full-2015-04-20/*"], UnicodeDecodeError='skip')
    lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
    ''' for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        for j in xrange(0, len(l[i])):
            l[i][j] = lmtzr.lemmatize(l[i][j])
            l[i][j] = lmtzr.lemmatize(l[i][j],'v')
    '''

    for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        words = l[i].split()
        word = [lmtzr.lemmatize(lmtzr.lemmatize(w,'v')) for w in words]
        return(" ".join(word))  
    return l


# input:  a list l of string
# output: a list containing the stemmed string in l
def stem(l):
    result = []
    stmr = PorterStemmer()

    for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        words = l[i].split()
        meaningful = [stmr.stem(w) for w in words]
        l[i] = " ".join( meaningful )

    return l




    return result

# input:  a list l of string
# output: a list of string where the stopwords are removed

def removeStopwords(l):

    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    for i in xrange(0, len(l)):
        words = l[i].lower().split()
        meaningful = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
        l[i] = " ".join( meaningful )

    return l

# input:  a list l of string
# output: a matrix where the (i,j) component is how many times 
#         the j-th word appear in the i-th document
def tf(l):

    result = [[]]
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   
                             tokenizer = None,    
                             preprocessor = None, 
                             stop_words = None)                     
    result = vectorizer.fit_transform(l).toarray()
    '''
        your code goes here...
    ''' 

    return result

# input:  a list l of string
# output: a matrix where the (i,j) component is the tf-idf value of the j-th word in the i-th document
def tfidf(l):

    result = [[]]
    tf_ = tf(l)
    #print(tf_[2])
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf = False)
    vectorizer.fit_transform(l)
    idf = vectorizer.idf_
    idf = idf -1 
    # scikit learn idf implementation see line 993 below    
    # https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py

   #print(idf[2])
    result = tf_*idf


    return result

# add any additional preprocessing you find helpful
def additional(l):
    result = []

    '''
        your code goes here...
    ''' 

    return result

# input:  a list l of string
# output: a feature matrix like object ready for training (2-D list, numpy array, sparse matrix)
# you may choose to use a subset of the previous functions that work best for you
def preprocess(l):
    print('preprocess done')
    removeStopwords(l)

  #  print(l[1])
    lemmatize(l)
    #stem(l)

    return l

# train_X: feature matrix for training
# train_t: list of labels for training
# val_X: feature matrix for validation
# val_t: list of labels for validation
# just print out your results, no need to return any value
def sec2c(train_X, train_t, val_X, val_t):

    cvalue = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
    print('LOGREG result:') 
    for c in cvalue:
        logreg = LogisticRegression(C=c)
        a = logreg.fit(train_X, train_t).score(val_X, val_t)
        print(a,c)


    cvalue = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
    print('SVM result')
    for c in cvalue:
        svm = LinearSVC(C= c)
        a = svm.fit(train_X, train_t).score(val_X, val_t)
        print(a,c)



    print('NB result')
    array = np.asarray(train_X)
    array[array==0]=1e9
    train_X = array.tolist()

    array = np.asarray(val_X)
    array[array==0]=1e9
    val_X = array.tolist()

    n = int(len(train_X)/8)
    nb = GaussianNB()   
    a = nb.fit(train_X,train_t).score(val_X,val_t)
    print(a)
    return
# input train_text, vali_text, test_text: each being a list of strings
#       train_labels, vali_labels: each being a list of labels
#

def sec2di(train_X, train_t, val_X, val_t, tf= False):

    if tf:
        print('Using TF')
    else:
        print('Using TF-IDF')
    cvalue = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
    print('LOGREG result:') 
    for c in cvalue:
        logreg = LogisticRegression(C=c)
        a = logreg.fit(train_X, train_t).score(val_X, val_t)
        print(a,c)

def useWord2vec(train_text, train_labels, vali_text, vali_labels, test_text):

 #  from gensim.models import Word2Vec

    # merge your texts here

    # train your word2vec here

    # train your classifiers here
    return 0
def parse(doc,text, label, test= False):

    if test:
        for sentence in doc: 
            review = BeautifulSoup(sentence).get_text()
            if len(review)>0:
                letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ",review)
                text.append(letters_only)
    else:
        for sentence in doc: 
            review = BeautifulSoup(sentence).get_text()
            if len(review)>0:
                if review[0:1] == '+':
                    label.append(1)
                else:
                    label.append(-1)    
                review = review[3:]
                letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ",review)
                text.append(letters_only)

def main():
# read data and extract texts and labels
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    train = open('small_train.txt', 'r')

    # do preprocessing
    trainSentences = re.split(r'\n', train.read())
    trainLabel = []
    trainText = []

    valid = open('small_valid.txt', 'r')

    validSentences = re.split(r'\n', valid.read())
    validLabel = []
    validText = []

    test = open('small_test.txt', 'r')    
    testSentences = re.split(r'\n', test.read())
    testLabel = []
    testText = []

    parse(trainSentences, trainText, trainLabel)
    print'parsed train'
    parse(validSentences,validText,validLabel)
    print'parsed valid'
    parse(testSentences,testText,testLabel, test= True)
    print'parsed test'

    pool.map(preprocess, [trainText, validText, testText])
    '''
    preprocess(trainText)
    print('preprocesed train')
    preprocess(validText)
    print('preprocesed valid')
    preprocess(testText)
    print('preprocesed test')   
    '''


    #ts = tfidf(trainText)
   # print(ts[2])
   # print(trainText[1]) 
    # train the model

    # make predictions and save them
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

But I received following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\jre\Desktop\SentimentAnalysis-master\SentimentAnalysis-master\main.py",
line 261, in <module
    main()   File "C:\Users\jre\Desktop\SentimentAnalysis-master\SentimentAnalysis-master\main.py",
line 222, in main
    valid = open('small_valid.txt', 'r') IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'small_valid.txt'
```

Can you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What part the the error don't you understand? `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'small_valid.txt'` You're trying to read a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I have small_valid.txt, I put it in the SentimentAnalysis-master file. but I am not sure why is not working, (I am really new to python)

Comment: Are you sure the file is available in the working directory you're running the script from? You could try catching the IOError and creating the file if it doesn't exist, then continuing as normal. Then you'd also find out where the program thinks the file should be.

Comment: `C:\Users\jre\Desktop\SentimentAnalysis-master\SentimentAnalysis-master\small_valid.txt`  is what needs to exist, because `main` is running from a script in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear: `No such file or directory: 'small_valid.txt'`. Move your file into this path:

```
C:\Users\jre\Desktop\SentimentAnalysis-master\SentimentAnalysis-master
```

or update the next code lines to use an absolute path:

```
train = open('C:\..path_to_file..\small_train.txt', 'r')

valid = open('C:\..path_to_file..\small_valid.txt', 'r')
```